running snowflake query using spark connect on a standalone cluster
I have configured a spark standalone cluster as follows:
# start spark master
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh

# start 2 spark workers
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2 $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-worker.sh spark://localhost:7077

# start spark connect
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --properties-file ./connect.properties --master spark://localhost:7077

My properties file is defined as follows:
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.plugins=io.dataflint.spark.SparkDataflintPlugin
spark.jars.packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,org.apache.hudi:hudi-aws:0.15.0,org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.5-bundle_2.12:0.15.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.5.1,software.amazon.awssdk:sso:2.18.40,io.dataflint:spark_2.12:0.2.2,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.16.0-spark_3.4,net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.16.1
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class

Now I start my pyspark job which connects with this remote instance and then tries to query the table. The snowflake query is fired correctly. It shows up in my Snowflake query history, but then I start getting failures.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.SnowflakeResultSetPartition
    at org.apache.spark.executor.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:71)

There is a longer stacktrace, but I am not sure of how to debug & then fix this.
I tried putting the relevant jars files in the jars folder. Also, when I run spark connect in client mode without a standalone cluster, the code runs fine.
So I suspect this is some misconfig on the executor end.
